# Coerce output of mapply function to dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind, mapply, coerce

```
library(verification)
```

Given several experiments (`AA,BB,...,`), I can run my code as follows using this `reproducible example`:

```
##################### EXPERIMENT AA

#my data in reality is continuous but I convert it to binary using a threshold 

obs=data.frame(replicate(10,round(runif(100))))
pred=data.frame(replicate(10,round(runif(100))))

#introduce a few NA values to simulate real world data.
obs1=as.data.frame(lapply(obs, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.85, 0.15), size = length(cc), replace = TRUE) ]))
pred1=as.data.frame(lapply(pred, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.85, 0.15), size = length(cc), replace = TRUE) ]))

#A=mapply(verify,obs1,pred1,frcst.type = "binary", obs.type = "binary")
pred1[,1]=NA # some points in pred1 have all NAs in reality

a=mapply(function(x, y) {if(all(is.na(y))) NA else verify(x, y, frcst.type = "binary", obs.type = "binary")
}, obs1,pred1,SIMPLIFY = F,USE.NAMES = TRUE)

aa=do.call('rbind',a)# put all paramters together and keep rownames for easy identification

##################### EXPERIMENT BB

obs=data.frame(replicate(10,round(runif(100))))
pred=data.frame(replicate(10,round(runif(100))))

#introduce a few NA values to simulate real world data.
obs2=as.data.frame(lapply(obs, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.85, 0.15), size = length(cc), replace = TRUE) ]))
pred2=as.data.frame(lapply(pred, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.85, 0.15), size = length(cc), replace = TRUE) ]))

#A=mapply(verify,obs1,pred1,frcst.type = "binary", obs.type = "binary")
pred2[,1]=NA # some points in pred1 have all NAs in reality

b=mapply(function(x, y) {if(all(is.na(y))) NA else verify(x, y, frcst.type = "binary", obs.type = "binary")
}, obs2,pred2,SIMPLIFY = F,USE.NAMES = TRUE)

bb=do.call('rbind',b)# put all paramters together and keep rownames for easy identification
```

1) I would like to coerce `aa` and `bb`to dataframe called `Answer` ignoring `$tab, $pred,$obs`. Note that `rownames` in `aa` and `bb` are the `colnames` of the input data (all inputs have same colnames)

2) For experiment `AA`, `BB`, `...` in `Answer`, I want to also have adjacent columns for each parameter from both experiments, e.g. `TS` in `Answer` will have `TS1`,`Ts2` as separate columns representing experiment AA and BB, respectively.